# For each unique value in a column check another column if another value appears in a data frame

Tags: r

I have a data frame of names and wish to check if there are any that aren't aged 21. My data looks a follows;

```
name      age
james     16
james     18
john      21
john      18
dave      17
dave      21
james     21
steve     18
dom       20
dom       21
steve     20
james     19
james     20
bill      18
```

So my problem is that I wish to retrieve every name from where someone with that name is not 21. So this should return;

```
 steve
 bill
```

I had a go at doing a for loop, looping around each name and checking if someone aged 21 has that name but I got a bit lost with a bigger data frame with the grouping of column 1 (names here)

Comment: It sounds like you mean "retrieve every name where no one with that name is 21"? "retrieve every name from where someone with that name is not 21" would return all the names in your example.

Comment: Yep thats what i mean phrased in a much better way, cheers

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible ways of interpreting your question. If you just want to print the names of all people who have an age that's not equal to 21 then try the following. Note that I decided to call your table `ages` for clarity in both of the following approaches:

```
for (i in 1:length(ages)) {
    if (ages[i, 2] != 21) {
      print(ages[i, 1]  
   }
}
```

But if you want to return everyone for which the age is less than 21, change the if statement to `if (ages[i, 2] < 21) {...}`

Hope that answers your question.

Comment: I think this is partly what I want, although for me it returns 'james' and 'james' who in the example shouldn't be returned as there is a james in the data of aged 21. Also, remember to close the bracket in the print argument.

Answer (score 1):

One `dplyr`-based option is a nested rowwise dataframe that you can filter with `%in%`:

```r
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

df <- data.frame(
  name = c("james", "james", "john", "john", "dave", "dave", "james", 
           "steve", "dom", "dom", "steve", "james", "james", "bill"), 
  age = c(16L, 18L, 21L, 18L, 17L, 21L, 21L, 18L, 20L, 21L, 20L, 19L, 20L, 18L))

df |>
  nest_by(name) |> 
  #> # A tibble: 6 × 2
  #> # Rowwise:  name
  #>   name                data
  #>   <chr> <list<tibble[,1]>>
  #> 1 bill             [1 × 1]
  #> 2 dave             [2 × 1]
  #> 3 dom              [2 × 1]
  #> 4 james            [5 × 1]
  #> 5 john             [2 × 1]
  #> 6 steve            [2 × 1]
  filter(!21 %in% data$age) |>
  pull(name)
#> [1] "bill"  "steve"
```

<sup>Created on 2023-08-31 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>